# "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile)"

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber, testng

Whenever doing a Maven Build..>clean install, I am facing this error. I have tried with different versions of plugins and adding testFailureIgnore attribute, but the issue still remains. Please find the POM.XML below-

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
        
            central
            Central Repository
            http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
            default
            
                false

```
    </repository>
</repositories>


<groupId>Cucumber-Automation-Niaz</groupId>
<artifactId>Cucumber-Automation-Niaz</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>4.10.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>

            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>NiazProject</projectName>  <!-- Replace with project name -->
                        <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-reports/advanced-reports</outputDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutput>target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json</cucumberOutput>
                        <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
                        <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8xH1.png)

Comment: As the error suggests, please check if you running the goal with JDK or JRE.

Comment: @Ramu I was using JRE back when I raised the issue here but now I have switched to JDK and to my surprise, the compiler is not able to find step definitions anymore. I am getting missing snippets error.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know which developmen IDE are you using If you are using STS/Eclipse go to java ->compiler->choose JDK rather than jre

Comment: JDK has been chosen. But now I am getting different sets of error like - "package org.testng.annotations does not exist"

Comment: Choose proper version of testing package